# One should lose reputation per downvote

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting

One should lose reputation points every time they downvote a post.

Comment: This already exists for answers. It costs 1 rep to downvote an answer.

Comment: Downvotes for questions used to cost 1 rep as well. But it was removed because people were holding back on downvoting bad questions - leaving the site littered with crap. Not that it isn't the case now, but at least a question with -3 tells me not to waste my time so I can go somewhere else.

Comment: You can flag your question for deletion by a moderator.  Editing it to say "Delete" is counter productive.

Comment: Not sure if you already knew this, but on Meta, downvotes are used to express disagreement. Your question isn't bad; it's just unpopular.

Comment: You might find [What is meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) useful. And please stop adding stuff to your question. For one it bumps the question as well so it keeps getting attention.

Comment: I only see 2 questions on your profile, one has a positive score. Don't take it personal - even Jeff Atwood (one of the founders) has sometimes posted massively unpopular questions. Just because people disagree with you, doesn't mean you're unpopular yourself.

Comment: Meanwhile - what rene says is correct: editing the question bumps it. I suggest one final edit to this post: removing the part where you comment on the downvotes. That kind of thing tends to attract more downvotes. I could make that edit, if you want. I think it's best to leave this question as objective as possible.

Comment: Only if you have to pay to upvote, too.  That way, we'd get a ton less pity upvotes.

Answer (score 19):

> One should lose out a bit every time he/she down-votes

Congratulations. This is implemented already on answers, not on questions (it was, not any more). And I think it is good that way.

You lose 1 reputation for every answer you down-vote. Questions don't have this, and it is actually a good quality control measure (how many will downvote bad questions when they lose reputation for it?). Downvoting on answers can be a done out of competition of another answerer, downvotes on questions never.

Upvoting should go without reputation loss. If only those with sufficient reputation can keep voting, this will have a bad influence on the site and will give a negative sentiment, something like "Sorry I don't upvote you. You have enough reputation already and I don't want to lose mine."

Comment: Indeed, senseless upvoting is harmful too. This is usually corrected by the community.

Comment: In a way it is. The other option is worse.

Comment: As Mystical pointed out, free downvoting on question is a good quality filter. That would get lost if the majority would hold back voting, which they did.

Comment: Only on per-site-metas, like Meta Stack Overflow, Meta English Language Learners. Meta Stack Exchange is 'just' another site (without an own per-site-meta)

Comment: @AllDaniSpringer You can request to have it deleted, or to have it dissociated from your account. Whether or not that will be honored is an open question. Deleted questions still count against a question ban, so it's best if you have a few good questions as a counterweight.

Comment: @S.L.Barth do disassociated posts count in the ban too?

Comment: @AllDani.com As far as I know, yes, dissociated posts will still count towards a ban. To prevent people from trying to dodge bans by asking for dissociation.

Comment: @S.L.Barth what, then, is the point of disassociation altogether?

Comment: @AllDani.com The purpose of dissociation is to not have your name on it anymore. It can preserve privacy and prevent embarassment. BTW a single heavily downvoted question won't get you banned; it takes several downvoted questions.

Comment: I see, thanks. But it will count in the balance and ruin positive record, I think.

Comment: Don't worry too much about that on meta. The thresholds for that are really low @AllDani.com

Answer (score 14):

> Isn't this what a community should be like?
>
> One suffers, all suffer. One gains, all gain!

No. Why do you think that? Should I also gain reputation for upvoting someone else's good answer?

> Just like a good counselor or parent (and what a teacher should be), will bend down and clean the mess with the kid, we too, should be part of what goes on.

How is taking away my reputation when I downvote helping to clean up the mess? Your arguments don't support your proposal at all.

Comment: Did you know that if we get people to cast less downvotes it means we have more high quality content.  I mean the average score of posts would obviously go way up.